# Computing a limit of an integral?

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose we have the following functions:

$$\bar{h_1}=\beta_A-\delta_A-\alpha-\delta_I+\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{S'}{S} $$

$$\bar{h_2}=-\epsilon\beta_A -\nu-\gamma-\mu+ c(\gamma+\mu)+c\frac{I'}{I}+c\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{A'}{A} $$

$$\bar{h_3}=-\epsilon\beta_I -\nu-\delta_I-\mu+ \frac{\delta_I+\mu}{c}+\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{I'}{c I}$$

$$\bar{h_4}=\beta_A-\delta_I+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{A'}{A} $$

where $c$ is a constant such that $\frac{\delta_I+\mu}{\epsilon \beta_I+\nu+\delta_I+\mu}<c<1$

Then we wish to compute:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\bar{h_i(s)}ds = \bar{H_i}<0\qquad i=1,\dots,4$$

The variables $S, A, I$ and  $R$ are bounded by $S+A+I+R=1$.

I was reading a paper that computes these limits but I didn't fully understand their methodology.

**EDIT:**

They have the limits:

$$\bar{H_1}=\beta_A-\delta_A-\alpha-\delta_I$$
$$\bar{H_2}=-\epsilon\beta_A-\nu-\gamma-\mu+c(\gamma+\mu)$$
$$\bar{H_3}=-\epsilon\beta_I-\nu-\mu-\delta_I+\frac{\delta_I+\mu}{c}$$
$$\bar{H_4}=\beta_A-\delta_I$$

Comment: It might be useful for everyone if you showed us this methodology, no? ;) otherwise we can’t help you understand it

Comment: @FShrike They just stated the answer! I can provide a link to the paper but there may be a paywall..

Comment: Which is?  It’s also not clear from your post what is a constant and what isn’t

Comment: I edited the question. variables are $S,A,I,R$ and rest are parameters. I also added in their solutions

Comment: I know the parameters will remain as constants due to division. My issue is with the state variables where we have $ln(0)$ terms..

Comment: There is missing relevant information here. How are the variable terms individually bounded? Are they positive? Do they decay to $0$ as $t\to\infty$? If so, with what growth rate? These are important to solve the limit. I have made all relevant assumptions on my answer to get their solutions: their solutions are however incorrect if one drops these assumptions, so, the assumptions are important

Comment: all variables are $\geq 0$ with $S+A+I+R=1$. So they are bounded by $0\leq V \leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$There is a lot of unnecessary detail here, and lots of missing detail too (more on that later). The constants $k$ will integrate to $kt$, and division by $t$ leaves them all at $k$. Notice all the limits in the answers are just the constant terms, so all we need to verify now is that the variable terms $S’/S$ etc. tend to $0$ in the limit. The procedure is the same for all of them, so I will use a general letter $V$ for variable. We assume $V(t)\neq0$ for any $t$, but that’s ok since we know this already in order for the $h$ functions to be well defined. I will assume that the variable functions are positive.

$$\int_0^t\frac{V’}{V}\d t=\ln(V(t))\Big|_0^t$$

Notice that $V(t)\le1$ always by the hound you gave, $S+A+R+I=1$ and the assumption I am making which is that the variables are positive quantities (or you can just assume they are bounded). However in order for their answer to be correct, we need that $\ln(V(t))$ is a bounded function also, or more generally that $\ln(V(t))\in o(t)$ as $t\to\infty$. This means that $V$ doesn’t blow up with exponential growth, nor does it decay exponentially to $0$ for large $t$. If you assume the $h_i$ are bounded then this is also sufficient, along with the assumption the $V$ are bounded.

With those assumptions: $$\frac{\ln(V(t))-\ln(V(0))}{t}\to0$$As $t\to\infty$. The integrals of the variable terms have vanished in the limit, and only the constants remain.

Comment: I did comment regarding your question(s), I'm not sure if you saw it(above).

Comment: @Math I see. A bound $0\lt V\lt1$ is good but technically not quite strong enough. If $V(t)\to0,t\to\infty$ with exponential - or faster - decay then there is a problem in the limit, the logarithm does not vanish. But whatever, it likely doesn’t matter if we had to ability to read the full paper for context

Comment: The paper: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1468121821001942?token=0A3978C2AA74B319C70472AAC9657504F82F231F9B599CC17B217AC97EF5E9B0C4A24F0601B1136C4F136FA6FA9EC2CB&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220516141251. My question arose from the top of page 15 in the pdf

Comment: If you read carefully they say: “Based on $(30)$ ...” where $(30)$ is the bound: $\epsilon\le S,A,I,R\le1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon\gt0$. This satisfies the assumptions I made: $V$ is bounded above and is bounded away from $0$, so $\ln(V)$ is bounded and vanishes upon division by $t$ as $t\to\infty$. That wraps up all concerns

Comment: Thank you, I was being silly! Once again, thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @Math  You're welcome

Comment: Could you have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452433/why-were-these-bounds-chosen. It is a follow up of this question. Thank you :)